# Batch selecting data from sybase ase 15.0.3 causes crash?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sqoop

Trying to pull about 100GB of data out of 2 tables. This issue isn't specific to sqoop as I can recreate it in a simple java application executing the queries. The query contains a simple

```
select id, xml from table where CONFIG
```

where CONFIG is different attempts at chunking the content into segments. Eventually one of the queries will fail and cause a

```
timeslice -1501 error, current process infect
timeslice error: spid 41 exhausted its 'time slice' of 100 milliseconds and 
additional 'cpu grace time' of 1500 ticks ( 150000 milliseconds). It has been 
marked for termination.
```

I have tried putting the database in read only mode, turning on auto truncating on checkpoints, using a stored procedure and just executing it over and over in a java application, and using jconnect and jtds for managing the connection. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: It's not clear what your end goal is, if you just want to save them to a file, create a view and bcp out the view. You should also create appropriate indexes based on your CONFIG.

Comment: The end goal is to run the data through a map/reduce program to be stored into hadoop and bcp is an option but I would really like an alternative. I would also like to under stand why it would cause the sybase instance to crash/restart. Thanks for looking Meet

Answer (score 0):

A time slice error is, simply put, caused by a bug in the Sybase ASE product. These timeslice errors are rare however. Why it happens? Well, that's what a bug is: nobody intended it to occur.

Recommended actions are:

- upgrade to a more recent version of ASE, like ASE 15.7 SP131 or later. ASE 15.0.3. is very old and countless issues have been fixed and improved since that time.
- increase the config setting for 'grace time'. If you're lucky, the query will then complete, but it is also quite possible it will just timeslice again.
- changing the optimization goal/criteria could be tried. You did not include any specifics here though, but if you have the current optimization goal set to 'allrows_dss', try setting it to 'allrows_oltp' and see if that fixes the issue.

Upgrading your ASE version, as in the first bullet above, is by far the best action to take though.

Comment: Thanks will give the optimizations a try and if not try to talk the dba's into trying an upgrade.